# Transforming vs changing frames of UIViews?

Tags: ios, uiview, orientation, transform, frame

What is/are the difference/s between applying translation and scale transformations to a view and simply setting them a new frame? It is only that transformations could be animated, or there are more things to be considered?

I'm specially thinking of views that should change in position and/or size when changing the device's orientation.

Thanks

Comment: You can animate frame change as well. I guess translations are just easier because they do all calculations for you, like rotations etc... Some animations are just harder to do on frame changes,because you need to calculate it manually

Answer (score 1):

One key point, especially when you're changing device orientation, is that the frame will be recalculated after the rotation. Setting the frame prior to rotation will not impact what the frame is after rotation. In this case, using a transform might be more useful because the frame will then be recalculated based on the transform property. One caveat from Apple's [documentation](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/UIKit/Reference/UIView_Class/#//apple_ref/occ/instp/UIView/frame):

> WARNING
>   If the transform property is not the identity transform, the value of this property is undefined and therefore should be ignored.

I have found that setting a scale transform usually does not result in the behavior I want; it actually STRETCHES the view out, which (depending on the settings of the view), could stretch out all of the images, buttons, etc. in your view and make it look terrible.

Usually the behavior that I actually want is actually to change the constraints on the view. Because the frame is recalculated after rotation based on the constraints, this approach is much more friendly to use with device rotation than simply changing the frame. It's also possible to animate constraint changes.

Finally, something really useful I discovered recently is that it's possible to create an outlet to a constraint you created in interface builder, so you can still lay out your view in interface builder but then change the constraints programatically.

Answer (score 0):

Frame describes both the size and the relative location (origin) of the view in superview, while transform while CGAffineTransform is a 3 by 3 matrix describing the coordinate system in another coordinate system. Please refer to the reference of CGAffineTransform for more details:

https://developer.apple.com/library/mac/documentation/GraphicsImaging/Reference/CGAffineTransform/#//apple_ref/c/macro/CGAffineTransformMake

Most commonly used method to transform a view object in iOS:

https://developer.apple.com/library/mac/documentation/GraphicsImaging/Reference/CGContext/index.html#//apple_ref/c/func/CGContextFlush

Also here's another answer that might be helpful:

[IOS view transformation modifies frame?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10712235/ios-view-transformation-modifies-frame)